# texshop cannot find xelatex or LuaLatex

Tags: mac

I recently reinstalled MacTex on my mac (OS 10.8.4).  The distribution of TexShop is new, version 3.26.  For some reason, xelatex and lualatex have disappeared from the pull down menu of tex options.  I've tried putting these lines at the top of the files:

% !TEX TS-program = xetex or % !TEX TS-program = xelatex

but my papers still won't tex.  I've checked the path, there is a copy of xetex (xelatex) in that location.  The paper will tex on a different machine which mysteriously has xelatex in the pull down menu.  Can anybody help me to turn on that option?

Comment: If all else fails, attempt a complete re-install. It may take a couple of minutes, but it sure is shorter than the time you've been waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Last time I've got something like it, I deleted the `TeXShop` folder of my personal library, quit and restarted TeXShop  and it worked. (This Library is hidden by default in Mountain Lion but you can access it by opening the `Go to` menu, choosing the option `Go to folder` and then entering `~/Library`.) In your case, maybe removing the `Engines` subfolder of this `TeXShop` folder and then quitting and restarting will be enough.

Comment: This absolutely worked for me, thank you SO much for the help!